# Plot discontinuous line graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a rather involved plotting procedure and I am trying to automate it to the best of my abilities and I seem to be loosing steam.  Lets say I have the following lists:

```
L2_US =[1.550,17.8781291,35.618459,53.191329,70.5660164,87.7105627,104.591588,121.174089,137.421217,153.294033,168.751236,183.748849,198.23988,212.17392,225.496694,238.14954,250.068807,261.185153,271.422729,280.698215,288.919676]
L4_US =[373.62,363.23,353.76,345.12,337.23,330.04,323.48,317.51,312.09,307.16,302.71,298.69,295.08,291.86,289.00,286.47,284.27,282.38,280.77,279.44]
L2_DS =[0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950,1000]
L4_DS =[279.07,276.52,299.70,298.72,297.66,296.52,295.27,293.91,292.41,290.76,288.92,,286.85,284.48,281.71,278.27,424.15,386.02,356.22,332.58,313.69,298.62]
```

`L2_US` and `L2_US` are the x and y coordinates of line 1
`L2_DS` and `L2_DS` are the x and y coordinates of line 2

In this application line 1 and line 2 will only have one intersection and I need to:

1. Find the intersection point
2. Plot line 1 till the intersection
3. Plot line 3 after the intersection

Here is the code I have developed so far:

```
import os, csv, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from itertools import product

#Find the closest Momentum values between the two profiles
a,b = sorted(product(L4_DS,L4_US), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]))[0]

#Get index of closest momentum values
ds_index = L4_DS.index(a)
us_index = L4_US.index(b)
print 'ds index is '+ str(ds_index)
print 'us indes is ' + str(us_index)

#Ignore the main plot,  my question pertains to the second axis plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_ylabel('Stage (m)',color='b')
ax1.set_xlabel('Distance (m)')

#Begin of subplot
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

#Upstream Momentum
ax2.plot(L2_US[0:us_index], L4_US[0:us_index], 'r-',label='Momemtum')

#downstream momemtum
ax2.plot(L2_DS[ds_index:], L4_DS[ds_index:], 'r-',label='Momemtum')
ax2.set_ylim([0.8*min(L4_DS),1.2*max(L4_DS)])
ax2.set_ylabel('Momemtum (m$^3$)',color='r')
plt.title('HW_8 Problem 3', fontsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

This code finds plots the first line till where the interpolated value would be and second line from the closest `L4_DS` value to the desired interpolated value, but it is not a complete step function.  I don't know the best way to perform the interpolation and the interpolated value to each of the lines.